# Filtering list of Users in User form field type

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform

I've been unable to determine if/how the list of users can be filtered.  The example below from [User form field type](http://docs.joomla.org/User_form_field_type), shows the filter in use, but I've been unable to come up with how to specify the group(s) to include in the list.

```
<field name="modified_user_id" type="user"
    label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_MODIFIED_BY_LABEL"
    class="readonly"
    readonly="true"
    filter="unset" />
```

Surely, if you have thousands of users, this list can be reduced to a particular user group somehow - am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/filtering-list-of-users-in-user-form-field-type/22070#22070 - New option in user field type allows filtering users by group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use

```
<field name="modified_user_id" 
  type="user"
  label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_MODIFIED_BY_LABEL"
  desc="A_DESCRIPTION_IS_ALWAYS_GOOD"/>
```

It creates a modal field that display a list of users that you can filter by group by selecting the combo box on the top right of the modal window.

If you need a simple combo box and you don't mind having the user group hard-coded you can use

```
<field name="modified_user_id_2" 
                type="sql"
                label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_MODIFIED_BY_LABEL"
                desc=""
                query="SELECT u.id , u.name FROM #__users as u inner join #__user_usergroup_map AS ugm ON ugm.user_id = u.id where ugm.group_id=8"
                multiple="single" 
                key_field="id" 
                value_field="name"
                />
```

And replace 8 by the user group id of your choice.

EDIT:
The function of the filter attribut is not to filter the displayed values of the field. It's more of a cleaning function that process the input value **after** the form is submitted. 
In this case it has little use as the 'user' field can only output a user id, but in a text field you could use the 'INT' filter to make sure the user enter a number.

The available values for the filter attribute are:

- INT:       An integer,
- UINT:      An unsigned integer,
- FLOAT:     A floating point number,
- BOOLEAN:   A boolean value,
- WORD:      A string containing A-Z or underscores only (not case
  sensitive),
- ALNUM:     A string containing A-Z or 0-9 only (not case sensitive),
- CMD:       A string containing A-Z, 0-9, underscores, periods or
  hyphens (not case sensitive),
- BASE64:    A string containing A-Z, 0-9, forward slashes, plus or
  equals (not case sensitive),
- STRING:    A fully decoded and sanitised string (default),
- HTML:      A sanitised string,
- ARRAY:     An array,
- PATH:      A sanitised file path,
- USERNAME:  Do not use (use an application specific filter),
- RAW:       The raw string is returned with no filtering,
- unknown:   An unknown filter will act like STRING. If the input is an array it will return an array of fully decoded and sanitised strings.

> [From the Joomla source code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php#L167)

Comment: Well, that would solve the immediate problem, though without the User dialog that works with the type=user, but it doesn't answer the question of how to use the filter for that field type.

Comment: Let me update my answer to explain the use of the filter attribut.

Comment: Well, I suppose then that the answer is that it cannot be done as asked, though the use of a filter seems meaningless since the field type provides a default form for selection - why would you further filter what that selection form returns - i.e. the user_id?

Comment: In this case, the filter attribut is useless, that's right.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, it is very easy to filtering the list of users in User form field type.

First in your manifest you should create a new type for your field, for example userFiltering (see below)

```
<field
        name="myUser"
        type="userFiltering"
        label="LABEL"
        description="DESCRIPTION"
/>
```

In the fieldset of the manifest, add the attribute 'addfieldpath' with the path of your new field type declaration (see below)

```
<fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/fields">
```

Finaly in the path "/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/fields", create a file userfiltering.php with the code below

```
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die();

class JFormFieldUserfiltering extends JFormFieldUser {

public $type = 'userfiltering';

protected function getGroups()
{
    $groups = array();
    $groups[] = 11; // put here the list of the groups you want to filter
    return $groups;
}
}
```

That's all

Comment: Could you please check if this is still possible? I tried it but get error loading from file.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a new option in Joomla 3.8.2.
Field type "user" has the option "groups".

```
<field
    name="partner_id"
    type="user"
    label="JGLOBAL_FIELD_MODIFIED_BY_LABEL"
    groups="10"
    required="true"/>
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone